# Outbound ssh times out, while telnet to the port 22 works

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, big-sur

After a recent upgrade (I guess) of macOS Big Sur 11.6 outbound SSH connections from my mac started to time out:

```
$ ssh 192.168.100.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.2 port 22: Operation timed out
```

However, `telnet` works, so this is not a connectivity problem:

```
$ telnet 192.168.100.2 22
Trying 192.168.100.2...
Connected to gw.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
```

I don't have any [antivirus](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8526350) software installed at the moment. What else may be causing this issue?

Comment: Is ssh enabled? Also, upgrades overwrite the sshd config in /etc, so any manual changes need to be reapplied.

Comment: What do you mean by "enabled"? I don't have any manual changes in ssh/sshd configs. I connect *from* my mac, so I'm not sure sshd config matters.

Comment: Ah, then question is rather whether sshd is running on the remote host

Comment: Yep, that is confirmed by the `telnet` call in the OP.

Comment: Ah, should have read the question better. Can you run `ssh -vvv …` and check the output for clues?

Comment: Same problem here, just psoted https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255263733 & https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/17r53f0/unable_to_ssh_to_internet_ssh_server_even_though/